# Does there exist SATA tape drives in the native 800GB - 1TB range?

Tags: backup, storage, tapedrive

The largest SATA tape storage I have been able to find is 160GB native, which is the Quantum DLT-V4.

Does anyone know of SATA (or USB3) tape storage with 800GB-1TB native capacity?

**Update**

It could also be a SAS tape drive. Can anyone recommend a SAS controller + SAS tape drive.

The SAS controller will only be used for the tape drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well certainly LTO-5 has a native uncompressed capacity of 1.5TB (they usually quote 3TB including compression).

[THIS](http://www.quantum.com/ServiceandSupport/SoftwareandDocumentationDownloads/LTO-5HH/Index.aspx) one is SAS based, can't seem to find any SATA ones, to be fair using SATA or USB for this kind of thing would be unusual.

Edit - Done some more digging and really can't find any LTO-5's that aren't either SAS, SCSI or FC - you could buy a SAS adapter pretty cheaply though.

Comment: I am very open for that solution. Do you have a recommendation for a SAS controller?

Comment: For tape solutions I'd always suggest Adaptec, they just work, but there are some great HP ones too - here's their compatibility guide, just plug in your backup software, OS and choose LTO-5 and it'll name at least one tested and compatible controller; http://www.quantum.com/DriveSWCompGuide.aspx

Comment: Do you mean in the "Drive Software Compatibility Guide" you linked to?

Comment: Yeah, it lists a controller used for testing if you fill it in right.

Answer (score 2):

DLT-S4 (800GB) has driver support for SATA mounting, though I can't find any actual devices that have SATA support. SAS, yes. SCSI-3, yes. But not SATA.

Comment: I had a feeling, that was a problem. I have now updated the question, so if you know of a SAS tape drive + controller you can recommend, then that is very interesting.